# Any way to dected if user is logged or not to a site?

Tags: session, cookies, authentication, login-control

i was wondering if is there any way to check if user is logged or not to another site domain, like facebook , google or twitter.

Is this legal and possible?

thanks

WHIOUT USING API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can see whether a login page or other login-only accessible page is in their browser history.

Forbes: [History Sniffing: How YouPorn Checks What Other Porn Sites You've Visited and Ad Networks Test The Quality of Their Data](http://www.forbes.com/sites/kashmirhill/2010/11/30/history-sniffing-how-youporn-checks-what-other-porn-sites-youve-visited-and-ad-networks-test-the-quality-of-their-data/)

> It’s based on your browser changing the color of links you’ve already clicked on. A script on the site exploits a Web privacy leak to quickly check and see whether your browser reveals that the links to a host of other porn sites have been assigned the color “purple,” meaning you’ve clicked them before.

[Mozilla has blocked this "feature" of CSS](http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/) because it's super sketchy.  Don't stalk your users without their permission.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the API's provided by the sites:

1. Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/
2. You were unclear with what you meant w/ the google, but I'm presuming you mean google+ as it - is related to your other ones, which are social networks: - https://developers.google.com/+/api/
3. Twitter: dev.twitter.com

Edit: upon reading a bit more into it, you have to make sure that your users are giving their consent also.

Edit: Since you seem so against using API's, which I don't have the slightest clue why you would be, there isn't exactly an easy way to do it w/o using apis, due to security. Atleast, there isn't a reliable way.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to check it. Some being hacky, other the way it is supposed to be checked.

With facebook for example, you can use their api and call the method: FB.getLoginStatus 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

A hackier alternative (altough not recommended) is to load the website in a script tag and catch the error in javascript. Often the specific details of the error will difer. This is not recommended

Is it legal? Well this isn't the best place to ask for legal advice, but I'm pretty sure that it isn't legal (without consent) in countries which have adapted the so called cookie law

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite generic. Anyway the short answer is (obviously) NO.

No because cookies are not sent to different domains (other servers) : this means that if a user is browsing on My-Site, from the server side (of My-Site) is not possible to know if the user is logged in an another site, because no cookie arrives to me.

Now move on the client side. (the browser).
You could download from My-Site "malicious Javascript" that attempt to send me information (cookies for example) that arrived from other sites.

When this malicious Javascript attempt to stole information, must face with the 'same origin policy' (same domain,layer protocol and port).
In other words from Javascript you cannot access to informations/code that comes from another 'origin' (as defined before).

This is, more ore less,the theory,then security holes may exist.